# Java SE Sanning API Morena7

Tags: java, api, scanning

I try to use Morena 7 in my java desktop application to scan document.

I read morena documentation and download the API

But i have a problem in that line

```
 BufferedImage bimage = SynchronousHelper.scanImage(device);
```

It's like  SynchronousHelper class is not found.

Someone have an idea please?

Thanks!

Comment: configure proper runtime classpath

Comment: OK. But i work with Netbeans. Netbenas configure automatically classpath if you add externe JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all.

I found the mistake, the SynchronousHelper.java is in the full package that i've download

**In the "examples" directory.**